# My wifi is greyed out in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, broadcom, wifi-configuration

I have a HP DV6 7040 tx

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=5277771&lc=en&cc=in&dlc=en&os=4132&sw_lang=

My wifi card is Broadcom bcm4313. My wifi was working fine in windows 8 till sept 3. Then i updated the BIOS to F.28 from F.24 using the official update file from the HP site. Now, my wifi is greyed out and doesn't turn on whenever i press the f12 key. It remains orange.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try the hardware switch.

Comment: Or a `FN` + `F1-F12` keys. Not all laptops have a hardware switch. Some are toggled by this key combo. Look at your `F1-F12` keys and look for something that looks like a WiFi signal or has the little radio waves/tower on it.

Comment: that doesn't work. I tried hitting the switches. F12 key does not turn it on (F12 key works anyway. I have tested it)